# Why does Javascript Intellisense work in some situations but not others?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I'm confused about how Intellisense works in Visual Studio Code with Javascript (this is using Jasmine and Protractor btw).

I have the line `var input = element(by.css('[ng-model=query]'))` in my test.

Now on the next line, I type `input.sendKeys(` and as soon as I type the left parenthesis, the parameter hints window popups up and shows the hints for the `sendKeys` method:

[image]

However, if I complete that line of code and move my cursor over `sendKeys` and hit `ctrl+shift+space`, the parameter hints window shows me the `it` function instead of `sendKeys`

[image]

I'm further confused by the fact that Intellisense doesn't seem to know about the `sendKeys` method when I begin typing it

[image]

But after I finish typing `sendKeys` and type the left parenthesis, Visual Studio **does** pull up the parameter hints for it (as in the first screenshot).

My two questions:

- Why does Visual Studio Code pull up the correct parameter hints for `sendKeys` when I'm typing them, but doing `ctrl+shift+space` to pull up parameter hints doesn't show parameter hints for the function that my cursor is over?  This behavior is the same for other functions as well; I'm just using `sendKeys` as the example.
- Why doesn't Intellisense suggest `sendKeys` even though the parameter hints seem to know about `sendKeys`?

Comment: Maybe extension bug. What's the signature of `element()` function?

Comment: `(element: string | Element | Document | Window | JQuery<HTMLElement> | ArrayLike<Element> | (() => void)): JQLite`